# User login failure while connect to MSSQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Trying to connect to MS SQL server from Java using JDBC:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://GM\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Northwind";
connServer.dbConnect(url, "sa","sa");
```

Got exception while connect:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://GM\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:1157e4ca-ae88-4e41-b60c-d93b808ba990
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:279)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:99)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4346)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Test.ConnectMSSQLServer.dbConnect(ConnectMSSQLServer.java:19)
    at Test.ConnectMSSQLServer.main(ConnectMSSQLServer.java:48)
```

I'm expecting to connect by using SQL server authentication. For this reason I changed password for `sa` user to `sa`. I can connect with SQL server authentication from SQL server management console, by using `sa` user. But one thing is disturbing me is red cross on user `sa`:

[image]

Why it is there. Is it somehow related to reason I can't connect to DB?

UPD

I have created user `tst` with password `tst` and did mapping to NorthWind DB:

[image]

Code:

```
connServer.dbConnect(url, "tst","tst");
```

But got the same error. By the way red crosses on `tst` and `sa` users are missing now.

Tried to add `tst` to sysadmins, but got error:

[image]

Comment: It's a disabled login. You need to right click on the sa account, go to Status and enable it.

Comment: That image shows the `sa` account  is disabled.

Comment: I don't ,however, recommend having an application having system adminsitrator priviledges. Create a new login, and give that the permissions it needs and **only** the permissions it needs.

Comment: I added user new user `tst`, but got the same problem. More details in UPD in question body

Comment: YOur connection string says the default database is `AdventureWorks`. I can't see that database is on your Server, so (of course) the connection will fail.. You can't connect to something that doesn't exist,

Comment: Yes, it was `AdventureWorks`, but changing to `Northwind` not helped

Answer (score 0):

Best practice here would be to create a specific user to interface through.

That user can then have the specific permissions required attached to it. The DBA can thereby restrict the accounts access to limit any damage even if the connection details do get compromised somehow.

A lot of DBAs disable "SA" as a matter of course as its a known account.  I do it as a matter of course and advise my clients to do the same (most ignore the advice). Its not a case of being being paranoid about security, more are you paranoid enough.

Comment: I added user new user `tst`, but got the same problem. More details in UPD in question body

Comment: Quick test - under SERVER ROLES on the tst login, tick sysadmin, and try again.  Please note this a great gaping security hole, but it will help establish if there are permission issues.

Comment: Got error while attempting grant to sysadmins operation `Attempt to retrieve data for object failed`. MOre detailsin UPD

Comment: Does the account your accessing the database as have sysadmin rights? You may need to get your DBA to add them for you.  You can't grant sysadmin, unless your already a sysadmin.

Comment: I'm logged with windows authentication single account, that is Windows sysadmin. Where I can see is it sysadmin in SQL server either?